# AWS Cloudfront Suddenly Stopped Working for Static S3 Website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a website that is set up with Route53 -> CloudFront -> S3 Static Website.

I have been using Cloudfront to provide https to my s3 static website. This has been working for over a week now, but suddenly today I get the following error.

```
404 Error
Code: NoSuchBucket
Message: The specified bucket does not exist
BucketName: d2ilcae2jv5qmq.cloudfront.net
RequestId: 6F918C3646D448EC
HostId: YtVUA4n4lC2Jl7+ngq3dqFk9aNy9llfp28BrficUY2Pp18OesURm5sidp9o106sViHXTtB6n/xE=
```

The same Cloudfront distribution also has a behavior to forward /api/ to my ec2 instance which is working fine. When I access the bucket directly it also is working fine.

I deleted my distribution and recreated it to match the exact same settings. It worked fine... until it broke a couple hours later and gave the same error as the old distribution. I have checked that the S3 bucket worked in all cases.

I am honestly completely confused on what could be causing this. Why is the BucketName pointing to itself? Shouldn't it be pointing to the S3 bucket?

Comment: Amazon CloudFront  had some issues few days ago: https://status.aws.amazon.com/ . You might be observing some leftovers from these problems.

Comment: Check in your PhD if there are more info.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by PhD?

Comment: Personal Health Dashboard. The status.aws.amazon.com is global for everything, not account specific. PhD is only for your account. So maybe can see there any issues regarding CloudFront that affected specifically you.

Comment: I see that March 31st had an error in the CloudFront distribution, which would make sense why my website was broken yesterday. However, I recreated the distribution but it just broke around 2 hours ago. Should I just try recreating it for the 3rd time? What would you recommend?

Comment: Also, I am reading the error on March 31st, it mentions higher latency and propagation delays. However, I don't think this is my problem since my whole website is getting a 404 error. Thank you for your help

Comment: Don't know what else could be done/checked, apart from recreating it. Also you are the only one using it? Maybe someone else, or some process, changes it? Can have a look at CloudTrail to search for CloudFront API calls.

Comment: I am the only one developing the website. I do remember pushing a change to the S3 bucket. Could this possibly of caused the issue? I will try recreating it now.

Comment: This is very weird now. My new Cloudfront distribution isn't even working anymore. I have a feeling its something I am doing wrong. For my origin, should i be putting the example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com or the suggest website.com.s3.amzonaws.com? Thank you again for your help

Comment: If your bucket is in website mode, then it must be example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com. The other type works when you don't use website mode and use Origin Access Identity, or your bucket is public.

Comment: Thanks. At this point I'm just so lost, but I know there's not much you can do to help. The CloudFront started working again after I went to eat. Driving me nuts.

Comment: Maybe threre are more issues on CloudFront itself.

Comment: I'll note that this behavior would be *expected* if you configure the Cache Behavior settings to whitelist the `Host` header or all headers, when using an S3 website endpoint *and* you're accessing CloudFront using the system-assigned hostname `dzzzexample.cloudfront.net` in your browser (not accessing it with your own domain name `www.example.com`)... or a really incorrectly written Origin Request trigger function in Lambda@Edge.  Outside that, it should be impossible short of the introduction of a regression in CloudFront.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Everything is working fine now. I did not whitelist the host. Rather than it just not working, I was more confused at the fact things were breaking and working again without me doing anything. I will just write it off as a one time error. However, if I get this issue again I will investigate the it more since that means I am doing something wrong.